# Fuzzy matching in python/pandas

Tags: python

New to python and need some help. I have two datasets (df1 and df2) and I need to do a fuzzy match on a “name” column to pull in data from another file. Before I do the fuzzy match, I want to clean up the “name” column to get a better fuzzy match result, so I’m creating a new name column “name2” and striping this column of some specific words. I’m doing this for both dataset “name” columns. I then have some code that does the fuzzy match on the “name2” column, but I’m having a hard time pulling in the original “name” column, instead of the “name2” column. How can I do this? Additionally, how do I pull in another field from df2 based on the matching?

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
   'Name': ['Testing and information 1', 'Categories and information 2', 'Money and information 3', 'Time and information 4'],
    'Category': ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Testing and information example', 'Categories and information example', 'Money and information example'],
    'Type': ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3']
})

#Create Name2 and remove certain words

df1['Name2']  = df1['Name'].str.replace('example|and|information', "")
df2['Name2']  = df2['Name'].str.replace('example|and|information', "")

# empty lists for storing the matches later
match1 = []
match2 = []
k = []

# converting dataframe column to list of elements for fuzzy matching

myList1 = df1['Name2'].tolist()
myList2 = df2['Name2'].tolist()

threshold = 80

# iterating myList1 to extract closest match from myList2

for i in myList1:
   match1.append(process.extractOne(i, myList2, scorer=fuzz.ratio))
df1['Name from df2 Identified'] = match1
for j in df1['Name2']:
   if j[1] >= threshold:
      k.append(j[0])
   match2.append(",".join(k))
   k = []

# saving matches to df1
df1['Name from df2 Identified'] = match2
print("\nName from df2 Identified...")
print(df1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood what you want to accomplish, otherwise feel free to ask. Here's my attempt based on `df1` and `df2` from your code:

```py
fuzzy_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.Name2, columns=df2.Name2)
fuzzy_matrix = fuzzy_matrix.apply(lambda row: [fuzz.ratio(row.name, name2) for name2 in row.index], axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
fuzzy_matrix = fuzzy_matrix.astype('int')

THRESHOLD = 80
translations = fuzzy_matrix.where(lambda x: x > THRESHOLD, np.nan).idxmax(axis=1)
max_values = fuzzy_matrix.max(axis=1)
df1['identified_name'] = df1.Name2.apply(lambda name1: translations.loc[name1])
df1['identified_score'] = df1.Name2.apply(lambda name1: max_values.loc[name1])
df1['Type'] = df1['identified_name'].apply(lambda name2: df2.set_index('Name2').loc[name2, 'Type'] if not pd.isna(name2) else np.nan)
```

**Explanation**: There's nothing wrong with fuzzywuzzy's `process.extractOne`, but I found it interesting to generate a fuzzy-matching matrix which compares every `Name2` from `df1` with every other `Name2` from `df2`. The resulting `fuzzy_matrix` table looks as follows:

| Name2 | Testing | Categories | Money |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Testing 1 | 95 | 42 | 42 |
| Categories 2 | 42 | 96 | 45 |
| Money 3 | 42 | 45 | 94 |
| Time 4 | 56 | 48 | 50 |

From here, we set any values below a given `THRESHOLD` to `NaN` and then find out which index/column pairs in above table have the highest value. The resulting `translations` looks like this:

| Name2 | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| Testing 1 | Testing |
| Categories 2 | Categories |
| Money 3 | Money |
| Time 4 | nan |

The `Time   4` `Name2` from `df1` had no accurate enough match with `df2`'s `Name2`s above the threshold, so it is set to `NaN`.

The rest of the code simply adds 2 columns in `df1` in order to store the matched `Name2`. To provide an example of how to get values from `df2` into `df1` based on the best matching `Name2`, I added the `Type` column. The resulting `df1` looks like this:

|  | Name | Category | Name2 | Name from df2 Identified | identified_name | identified_score | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Testing and information 1 | Category 1 | Testing 1 | ('Testing ', 78) | Testing | 95 | Type 1 |
| 1 | Categories and information 2 | Category 2 | Categories 2 | ('Categories ', 83) | Categories | 96 | Type 2 |
| 2 | Money and information 3 | Category 3 | Money 3 | ('Money ', 71) | Money | 94 | Type 3 |
| 3 | Time and information 4 | Category 4 | Time 4 | ('Categories ', 33) | nan | 56 | nan |

If you want to get rid of any rows which had no match in `df2`, just use `df1.dropna(subset=['identified_name'])` (which would drop row 3).